# How to control project info generation only for the parent module

Tags: maven, maven-3

```
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
```

I am on a multi module project and would like to know how to generate this project information only for the parent and not for the child modules which inherit the parent. Should I be setting the `inherited` or `aggregated` to `false`

Comment: I couldn't get anything to work, not sure what I am missing here

Comment: Did you run in debug mode? (`-X`)?

Comment: How have you organized your pom.xml? Is it aggregation or inheritance? If it is aggregation, maven will automatically run/compile the modules defined in the parent. If it is inheritance, then I don't get the point of what you are trying to achieve. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Michael-O Asking Joe to try is not helpful. Obviously, he needs help to make this work.

Comment: My <myproject>/pom.xml contains all modules listed as <module>my-sub-module-A</module><module>my-sub-module-B</module> ... under <modules> tag. I am assuming this is configured for aggregation, correct?

Answer (score 2):

This question does not really make sense since the purpose of a parent project is to establish a link between modules. It is possible to [select a set of reports to generate](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/examples/selective-project-info-reports.html), but there is no option to run it only on a subset of modules.

If you are using inheritance, you may want to restructure your project using an aggregation `pom.xml`. Like this, you would be able to run reports on a given module (or on all if you run it on the parent aggregate).

If this does not answer your question, can you clarify? Thanks.

Comment: I am using a select set of reports to generate my site report. I was under the impression that if you can run this report on a single module which in turn aggregates reports of all individual modules. Does having a site report on a child module make sense?

Comment: Most of the links generated by the site command seems stale. e.g. If I click on any module under <myproject>/target/site/index.html it seems to generated an invalid link and fails.

Comment: The same behavior is seen if I try to click on the module link of a sub-module (e.g. When I click on the my-sub-module link on <myporject>/<my-sub-module>/target/site/index.html, it re-directs to <myporject>/<my-sub-module>/target/index.html and it fails). What am I missing here?